# sending notifications before event with javascript running nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I have a database of events and would like to send notifications to participants 10 minutes before the events. the events are stored in a Postgres database and using nodejs as the server.
i was wondering if querying the database once a day and use javascript setTimeout for each event depending on the time of the event is a good or bad idea. this kind of what i'm thinking

```
    const sendEmailToParticipants = (event) => {.......}

    const eventArray = getTodaysEvents();

    //from database, expecting less than 500 records
    //run from a node-cron
    eventArray.forEach((event) => {
        const when = calculateTillTenMinutesBeforeEvent(event)
        setTimeout(sendEmailToParticipants, when, event);
    })
```

any other better approach will be greatly appreciated.

i also thought about having a cron job but above seemed more efficient to me if it doesn't have side effects

Comment: Are you trying to run this code code everyday manually? I would recommend `node-cron`  as this is perfect use-case for cron job as it will do specific things on your application server at certain times without having to physically run them yourself.

I would not recommend you using `setTimeout()`

Comment: I'm using node cron, but instead of running the cron regularly to get the upcoming events,  just run it once a day. any particular reason why not use setTimeOut?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you using a solution like [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) for a more scalable approach.

With Agenda, you can schedule jobs with the same name, and a specific time to run, and run every 5 minutes ou less to do what you need.

Another approach is to use a queue service with a serverless implementation. Like [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sqs/) + [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/lambda/) in AWS ([here's a tutorial about it](https://medium.com/@mladen.bolic/aws-lambda-scheduler-123c1d1ec0)).

Comment: thank you!  both look great - does agenda require conversion to mongodb?